# Could not allocate ndarray

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, memory, face-recognition

I am having a memory issue and I can't explain why. I am attempting to iterate over some images, detect faces, and use a python package (DeepFace) to determine some attributes of all the faces in the image and save that off. I notice that my Ram almost immediately shoots up to very high usage (15/16 GB) and hovers around there the entire time it is running, and then usually crashes after going through about 20 images. That's when I get the error "Could not allocate ndarray". Below is my code.

```
import os
import cv2
import pandas as pd
from deepface import DeepFace
import gc

path="Documents/test images 2"
saved_path = "Documents/faces2"
valid_images =[".png"]
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('Documents/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

# Create empty dataframe to save results to
all_image_objects = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Image','Age','Gender','Race','Emotion']) 

for f in os.listdir(path):
    ext= os.path.splitext(f)[1]
    if ext.lower() not in valid_images:
        continue
    img_name=os.path.basename(f)
    img_name=os.path.splitext(img_name)[0]
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,f))
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        ROI = img[y-20:y+h+20,x-20:x+w+20]
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        try:
            demography = DeepFace.analyze(ROI, actions = ['age', 'gender', 'race', 'emotion'])
        # handling the case where no face is detetected
        except ValueError: 
            
            continue
        face_dict = {'Image':img_name,
                     'Age':demography["age"],
                   'Gender':demography["gender"],
                   'Emotion':demography["dominant_emotion"],
                   'Race':demography["dominant_race"]}
        index = [0]
        face_df = pd.DataFrame(face_dict, index=index)
        all_image_objects=all_image_objects.append(face_df,ignore_index=True)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(saved_path,f),img)
    gc.collect()
```

One of the things I've tried to do to control memory usage is add in the gc.collect() function based on some readings I did, but that seemingly had no effect. Is there any way to help understand what is taking up the memory? Each image is ~200-400 KB and my understanding was that I was only loading one at a time, so I'm confused about how I'm burning through so much RAM for this.

Edit: I have been trying to do some more troubleshooting using guppy, but whenever I try to profile the memory usage the kernel crashes. Below is what I'm attempting.

```
from guppy import hpy
h=hpy()
h.heap()
```

Which results in

```
Restarting kernel... 
 
[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: ba39c2f6076211eb91367085c2f42d08
[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: 9b49877e076411eb8c3e7085c2f42d08
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find something that alleviates this to some degree, but is far from perfect. Still get the same error but now instead of happening after 20 images it happens after about 2000. From keras I bring in the following

```
from keras import backend as K
```

After every iteration of the loop I run the following.

```
K.clear_session()
```